# Can't build Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

[image]

> error: /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoviesK-asfdnehdvvokvgecswpiwzqzwyxh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.framework: No such file or directory

i'm facing with this problem. I tried the methods such as deleting derived data, clean and building project again. but still the error is showing. Is there any other methods to solve this problem.

Comment: I have faced [similar problem](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift/issues/253#issuecomment-263111691). Reinstalling the pod fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and adding the framework again

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday with `Carthage` and the same SDK and managed to fix it by adding `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS` to `Framework Search Paths` in my project target `Build Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Following are steps you should follow 
1.
-Copy PodFile
-Place somewhere like on the Desktop
2.Delete all the pod file e.g.Xcworkspace ,pods from "Build Phases"
3.Create Podfile or paste previous Podfile and include all pods
4.Reinstall pods 
Build your project .

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the pods and do a clean build. Also must verify the paths being referenced in your pods file.

You may also need to check the headers path in your build settings of the project. An older reference of path in headers/libraries can also be the cause even if your pods are correctly configured.